# ListView with rounded corners only for top and bottom items

Tags: android, android-layout, listview, android-listview

Is there any way to implement ListView with rounded corners for top and bottom items, except providing different backgrounds for top, bottom and middle items? The key requirement is not to put ListView inside a container with rounded corners, but to handle the case when ListView height is bigger than screen height. So not the first and last visible items would have rounded corners, but the actual ones.

Comment: make a custom ListView and override its draw/dispatchDraw method